# Ajax not working - posted fixed PHP anyway

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

Html:

```
<form action="registerusers.php" method="POST">
    <input id= "uname" name="uname" placeholder="username" required>
    <input id="upassword" name="upassword" type="password"   placeholder="password" required>
    <button id="register" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg outline" onclick="javascript: validateForm();checkNameRegister();" >Register</button>
```

Ajax:

```
function checkNameRegister() {

$.ajax({
          url: "registerusers.php",
          data: { uname : "uname" , upassword : "upassword"},
          type: "POST",
          async: false,
          dataType: 'text',
          success: function(responseText) {
            alert(responseText);
          }
    });


};
```

php:

```
<?php
```

header('Content-Type: application/json');

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$alert1 = null;
$uname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, isset($_POST['uname'])); 

if ($uname === $_POST['uname'] ? $_POST['uname'] : ''){
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=users', 'root', 'redcardinal');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `usernames` WHERE `uname` = :uname';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":uname",$uname, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($uname));



$stmt->execute();
$hello = array(array());
if ($hello = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ? $hello != null : ''){
    $alert1 = "This name is taken.";
echo json_encode($alert1);
$conn = null;
$query = null;
}
elseif ($hello === null) {
    $alert2 = "This name is not taken.";
 echo json_encode($alert2);
}

}
catch (PDOException $e) { echo json_encode($e);
$conn = null;
$query = null;

}

EDIT: WILL PUT ADDITIONAL elseif HERE.

}
?>

<?php
```

header('Content-Type: application/json');

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
include 'check_name.php'; 

$uname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, isset($_POST['uname'])); 

if ($uname != null && $alert1 === null) { 
try {
$conn = new PDO  ('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=users', 'root', 'redcardinal'); 
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

$uname = $_POST['uname']; 

$upassword = password_hash(filter_input(INPUT_POST, isset($_POST['upassword'])), PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 



$stmt = 'INSERT INTO `usernames` (`uname`, `upassword`) VALUES (:uname,:upassword)'; 
$query = $conn->prepare($stmt); 
$query->bindParam(":uname",$uname, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($uname)); 
$query->bindParam(":upassword",$upassword, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($upassword)); 



$query->execute(); 
echo json_encode("Username/Password successfully created.");
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
}
elseif ($alert1 != null) { 

echo json_encode("Username/Password taken."); 
}

$query = null; 
$conn =null;
```

I basically changed the PHP as per suggested, the only other problem I can think of is the html or ajax.  Thanks

Comment: `if ($uname = isset($_POST['uname']) ? isset($_POST['uname']) : ''){` Should probably be `if ($uname = isset($_POST['uname']) ? $_POST['uname'] : ''){` to give you the value fro $_POST, and no a boolean true in $uname

Comment: A lot of your `if`s are doing assignments (=) rather than comparisons (==). I expect a few of your errors are arising from this if this is not intentional.

Comment: From [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php): _"The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned. That is, the value of "$a = 3" is 3. This allows you to do some tricky things"_. (Sometimes accidentally)

Answer (score 1):

You have your `if ($hello = null) {`

you need to change it to `if ($hello === null) {`

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$alert1 = null;

if ($uname = isset($_POST['uname']) ? isset($_POST['uname']) : ''){
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=users', 'root', 'password');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `usernames` WHERE `uname` = :uname';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":uname",$uname, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($uname));



$stmt->execute();
$hello = array(array());
if ($hello = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) && $hello != null){
    $alert1 = "This name is taken.";
echo json_encode($alert1);
$conn = null;
$query = null;
}
if ($hello === null) {
    $alert1 = "This name is not taken.";
 echo json_encode($alert1);
}

}
catch (PDOException $e) { echo json_encode($e);
$conn = null;
$query = null;
$alert1 = null;
}



 }
```

and about the second one, two things are wrong.

1. change `if ($uname != null && $alert1 = null) {` to `if ($uname != null && $alert1 === null) {` you need to make three === insted of 1 =.
2. again change `else ($alert1 != null) {` to `elseif ($alert1 != null) {` you make another if statement so you need to do esleif instead of else.

   error_reporting(E_ALL); 
   ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
   include 'check_name.php';

   $uname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, isset($_POST['uname']));

   if ($uname != null && $alert1 === null) { 
   try {
   $conn = new PDO        ('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=users', 'root', 'password'); 
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   $uname = $_POST['uname'];

   $upassword = password_hash($_POST['upassword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

   $stmt = 'INSERT INTO `usernames` (`uname`, `upassword`) VALUES   (:uname,:upassword)'; 
   $query = $conn->prepare($stmt); 
   $query->bindParam(":uname",$uname, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($uname)); 
   $query->bindParam(":upassword",$upassword, PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($upassword));

   $query->execute(); 
   }
   catch (PDOException $e) {
   print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "
   ";
   die();
   }
   }
   elseif ($alert1 != null) {

   echo json_encode("This name is already taken, choose another."); 
   }

   $query = null; 
   $conn =null;

   ?>

Comment: Thank you, I've changed the code as you suggested but now I believe I am having a problem with my AJAX call.  Will post that too. Thanks